# What type of legally binding document do I need to offer my own services and make a client responsible for their use of my own deliverables?

Tags: contract-law, liability, terms-of-service

Lengthy question. I offer software analysis services. I can tell a business what technology they need, how to put it together, and give them the materials to start hiring developers with. I don't want to be held liable for their misinterpretations of my information or incompetence if their software fails as part of a business model.

**TL;DR:** I want to provide services to a client that gives them valuable information and I don't want them to take me to court for any reason.

It seems like a variation of Terms of Service that I would have them sign.

Comment: "I don't want them to take me to court for any reason." - easy, don't go into business.

Comment: @DaleM's point is, I think, that no contact will prevent anybody from taking you to court.

Comment: it's clear what his point was, but it didn't make progress towards a solution.

Answer (score -1):

Indemnification & Liability clauses with terms regarding user's own responsibility for damages occurring from use including improper use and security. Examples can be found in most software agreement contracts.